# Can the acyclic models theorem be applied to relative homology?

Tags: category-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Can the acyclic models theorem be applied to relative homology?

In the book by Vick: *Homology theory: an introduction to algebraic topology* a chapter is dedicated on the creation of products for homology and cohomology, while making use of the acyclic models theorem and using it to prove the Eilenberg-Zilber theorem. Vick does this for singular homology, but notes that the constructions may be duplicated for relative homology. This is not clear to me.

Vick's definition of a free functor:

> Now fix a category $\mathcal{C}$. Suppose that $\mathcal{M}= \{M_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in\Lambda}$ is a specified collection
> of objects in $\mathcal{C}$. $\mathcal{M}$ will be called the models of $\mathcal{C}$. A functor $T$ from $\mathcal{C}$ to the
> category of abelian groups and homomorphisms is free with respect to the
> models $\mathcal{M}$ if there exists an element $e_\alpha\in T(M_\alpha)$ for each $\alpha$ such that for every
> $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$ the set
> $$\{T(f)(e_\alpha)\mid\alpha\in \Lambda, f\in \operatorname{hom}(M_\alpha, X)\}$$
> is a basis for $T(X)$ as a free abelian group. A functor $T$ from $\mathcal{C}$ to the category
> of graded abelian groups is free with respect to the models $\mathcal{M}$ if each $T_n$ is,
> where $T_n$ is the nth component of $T$.

I believe this is not very precise, since it should be added that $T$ is free w.r.t. $\mathcal{M}$ if the $T_n$ are free w.r.t. some subcollection of $\mathcal{M}$ (but this is a bit beside the point).

Then the acyclic models theorem says that

> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category with models $\mathcal{M}$ and $T,T'$ covariant functors from $\mathcal{C}$ to the category of chain complexes such that $T_n=0=T_n'$ for $n<0$ and $T$ is free with respect to the models $\mathcal{M}$. Suppose further that $H_i(T'(M_\lambda))=0$ when $i>0$ and $M_\lambda\in\mathcal{M}$ ($T'(M_\lambda)$ is acyclic in the positive dimensions). If there is a natural transformation $$\Phi: H_0(T)\Rightarrow H_0(T')$$ then there exists a natural transformation $$\phi: T\Rightarrow T'$$ which induces $\Phi$. If this holds for another natural transformation then they are naturally chain homotopic.

Concretely, I am trying to prove the following theorem as a corollary of the acyclic models theorem:

> Let $f,g:(X,A)\rightarrow (Y,B)$ be homotopic as maps of pairs. Then for the corresponding homomorphisms from $H_*(X,A)$ to $H_*(Y,B)$, we get $f_*=g_*$.

Which would require to prove that $S_*$ from the category of pairs of spaces to the category of chain complexes is a free functor with respect to some collection of models. First of all one needs to consider $S_n(X,A)=S_n(X)/S_n(A)$ as a free abelian group so that it has a basis. We can identify this with the free abelian group generated by $n$-simplices of $X$ whose image is not contained in $A$. However, I do not see how this allows us to write $S_n$ as a free functor, since the obvious choice: $\mathcal{M}=\{(\Delta^n,\emptyset)\}$, $\operatorname{Id}_{\Delta^n}\in S_n(\Delta^n,\emptyset)$, where $\Delta^n$ is the standards $n$-simplex, gives the set $$\{f+S_*(A)\mid f\in \operatorname{hom}((\Delta^n,\emptyset),(X,A))\}$$ which contains zero, so it is not really a basis.

My question is, whether an argument of this type is possible. How do I use the acyclic models theorem in a relative homology setting? Is it really necessary that this set forms a basis in order for the acyclic models theorem to work? (I think it is necessary that $T(f)(e_\alpha)\neq T(g)(e_{\alpha'})$ for all combinations of $f\neq g$ and $\alpha\neq\alpha'$ in order for the proof method Vick uses to work but I am not sure).